# Bootstrap 4 tabs with VuesJS in a loop - can't go back to the first tab

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using vueJS and Bootstrap tabs and can't get them to work properly. I can visit tab 1, tab 2, tab 3, tab 4, but then I can't go back to tab 1.
I can also go 1, 3, but then not 1 and 2. I can basically only go to the right

As these tabs are in a v-for loop, I add ids to each of them.
I have zero error/warning, each ID is unique.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg " style="width:100%;">
    <div class=" navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0" :id="'myTab'+form.id_item" role="tablist" style="display: flex; width:100%">
            <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a active" :id="'infosGenform-tab'+form.id_item" data-toggle="tab" :href="'#infosGenform'+form.id_item" role="tab" aria-controls="infosGenform" aria-selected="true">infosGenform</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a " :id="'inscrform-tab'+form.id_item" data-toggle="tab" :href="'#inscrform'+form.id_item" role="tab" aria-controls="inscrform" aria-selected="true">inscrform</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a" :id="'machineform-tab'+form.id_item" data-toggle="tab" :href="'#machineform'+form.id_item" role="tab" aria-controls="machineform" aria-selected="true">machineform</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a " :id="'comform-tab'+form.id_item" data-toggle="tab" :href="'#comform'+form.id_item" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">comform</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" :id="'myTabContent'+form.id_item">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'infosGenform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="infosGenform-tab">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'inscrform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="inscrform-tab">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'machineform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="machineform-tab">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'comform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="comform-tab">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it something you already experienced?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `jQuery` and use `vuejs` instead to navigate tabs. Here is my approach.

In your tab navigation add this `@click.prevent="showTab(1)"`. The `.prevent` is to prevent default action of going to another page. In your other navigation do the same i.e `@click.prevent="showTab(n)"`.

This means you will have to add a new vuejs method `showTab(value)`like below.

```html
showTab(value){
  this.tab = value
}
```

In your tab content use vuejs show `v-show="tab == 1"` Find the full code below.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg " style="width:100%;">
            <div class=" navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0" :id="'myTab'+form.id_item" role="tablist" style="display: flex; width:100%">
                    <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a active" :id="'infosGenform-tab'+form.id_item" @click.prevent="showTab(1)" role="tab" aria-controls="infosGenform"
                            aria-selected="true">infosGenform</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a " :id="'inscrform-tab'+form.id_item" @click.prevent="showTab(2)" role="tab" aria-controls="inscrform"
                            aria-selected="true">inscrform</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a" :id="'machineform-tab'+form.id_item" @click.prevent="showTab(3)" role="tab" aria-controls="machineform"
                            aria-selected="true">machineform</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-evt-li">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-evt-a " :id="'comform-tab'+form.id_item" @click.prevent="showTab(4)" role="tab" aria-controls="home"
                            aria-selected="true">comform</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="tab-content" :id="'myTabContent'+form.id_item">
            <div v-show="tab == 1" class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'infosGenform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="infosGenform-tab">
                1
            </div>
            <div v-show="tab == 2" class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'inscrform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="inscrform-tab">
                2
            </div>
            <div v-show="tab == 3" class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'machineform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="machineform-tab">
                3
            </div>
            <div v-show="tab == 4" class="tab-pane fade show itra-light-grey-bgr" :id="'comform'+form.id_item" role="tabpanel"
                aria-labelledby="comform-tab">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            tab: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showTab(value){
            this.tab = value
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope this answer will help.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that's a much better idea!